# Windows server not assigned with ip address before login

Tags: windows, ip-address, windows-server, windows-server-2019

I am having this weird problem where a physical hp server cannot be seen on my network after an unplanned shutdown/restart, I have to log in manually, and only after that, I can be ready to use network stuff like sql server, remote desktop, anydesk, iis and a plethora of other network related software, my guess is that the server is not receiving an IP address before logging in, I have searched through event viewer, logs and could not find anything wrong, dhcp is working fine, I have also tried static ip, any ideas?